# Perl - use 0 if string is empty

Tags: perl

When using arithmetic expressions in combination with an undefined or empty string, perl throws an error. Is there a clean way to use zero in case a string is empty?

This does not work:

```
$x = 1 + $emptyVar
```

In bash you could use something like this for instance to use zero if the variable $emptyVar is empty:

```
x=1+${emptyVar:-0}
```

I am looking for something similar as this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  e.g.:

```
$x = $emptyVar;
$x += 1;
```

or maybe:

```
$x = 1 + ($emptyVar // 0); # defined-or operator
```

or maybe:

```
{
  no warnings 'uninitialized';
  $x = 1 + $emptyVar;
}
```

Of these, I usually use the second one.  If the level of perl I'm using doesn't have defined-or, then a simple or (`||`) works fine, too.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: the question says undefined or *empty string*, so `$x = 1 + ($emptyVar || 0);` instead

Comment: @ysth - true, though when likening to shell where "empty" and "undef" are largely indistinguishable, I figured there was a good chance that's what OP meant.

Comment: `++($x = $emptyVar)`

Comment: I find the defined-or useful in case like: exit 0 if (fork // -1) -- otherwise I cannot distinguish between fork failing (unlikely but possible) and child process. tried with  strace -f -e trace=process perl -le 'print "foo" if (fork // -1)' to see this may be useful...